# A not so simple Second order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation

```
eqn = y''[t] - a *Cos[x[t]]*x''[t] - a *Sin[x[t]]*(x'[t])^2 == 0;
```

with initial conditions `y[0]=0` and `y'[0]=0`. And `y[t]=a Sin[x[t]]` is the connection between the two variables x and y.

Help please.

Comment: What issues with [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) you have? It's pretty simple.

Comment: You have two dependent variables, `x` and `y`. You need two equations.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon. You are right. I have just added that equation to my question. Could you kindly suggest how to solve this system?

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry for the poor notation. x is the function of time. Thanks @David

Comment: So you eqn is `eqn = y''[t] - a*Cos[x[t]]*x''[t] - a*Sin[x[t]]*(x'[t])^2 == 0 /.
   y -> Function[t, a Sin[x[t]]] // FullSimplify` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation only has a constant solution. You can see this by replacing for `y`:

```
eqn /. y -> ( a Sin[x[#]] &)
(*result: -2 a Sin[x[t]] x''[t]^2 == 0*)
```

So your differential equation actually is $\sin(x) \left(\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial t^2}\right)^2=0$. The only way to satisfy this equation is $x=const$.